# How to write selecting Multiple count group by Date PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot

Help me selecting multiple counts with score ranges by date with postgreSQL

```
|date|score|
|----|-----|
|12/1|2    |
|12/1|4    |
|12/1|5    |
|12/2|3    |

|date|low0-2|high3-4|perfect|
|----|------|-------|-------|
|12/1|1     |1      |1      |
|12/2|0     |1      |0      |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5f481dbedcd5ead2105a19daf021d5b5)

You could do this, using the `FILTER` clause for group aggregations which is a special Postgres way:

```
SELECT
    my_date,
    COUNT(score) FILTER (WHERE score BETWEEN 0 AND 2) AS "low0-2",
    COUNT(score) FILTER (WHERE score BETWEEN 3 AND 4) AS "high3-4",
    COUNT(score) FILTER (WHERE score = 5) AS "perfect"
FROM
    scores
GROUP BY my_date
ORDER BY my_date
```

Otherwise you could take the more SQL Standard way using the `CASE` clause:

```
SELECT
    my_date,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN score BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS "low0-2",
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN score BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS "high3-4",
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN score = 5 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS "perfect"
FROM
    scores
GROUP BY my_date
ORDER BY my_date
```

Comment: thank you! bottom one works perfect on redshift too.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your example correctly, the second part is what you want to have as output from the first, right?

Here you go:

```sql
SELECT
    date,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE score < 3) AS "low0-2",
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE score > 2 AND score < 5) AS "high3-4",
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE score > 4) AS "perfect"
FROM
    my_scores
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Producing (used real dates for test):

```
    date    | low0-2 | high3-4 | perfect 
------------+--------+---------+---------
 2018-12-01 |      1 |       1 |       1
 2018-12-02 |      0 |       1 |       0
(2 rows)
```

Interactive example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2a7f160954020cdffc799e8a02491dc5